# What to do when you have the same tag in different category?

Tags: postgresql, supabase, flutterflow

I am designing the database for my new app. Within the app, there is a business profile that includes categories and tags. Depending on the category, different tags are displayed. I have a question regarding the situation where a tag repeats in different categories.

Example:

Category: Clubs
Tag: **Rooftop**

Category: Restaurants
Tag: **Rooftop**

I had thought about creating the same tag twice and associating it with each of the categories.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is a many-to-many (M:M) relationship between categories:tags. This is a **very common scenario** and is typically resolved by introducing a third table (let's call it `profiles`) containing the ids of the other related tables and any intersection data (data related to the combination). You **do not duplicate** either the category or the tag. Something like: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/WuXeXVSr))

```
create table categories (category_id   integer  generated always as identity
                                                primary key
                        , name         text     not null
                                                unique
                        , description  text
                        );

create table tags(tag_id   integer  generated always as identity
                                    primary key
                 ,name     text     not null 
                                    unique
                 );

create table profiles(category_id integer not null 
                                          references categories(category_id)
                     ,tag_id      integer not null 
                                          references tags(tag_id)
                     ,effective_dt date   not null default current_date
                     ,constraint   profiles_pk 
                                           primary key(category_id, tag_id)
                     );
```